# Communication between web site and windows service

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, windows-services, webserver, communication

I have a web site written in c# (MVC) and a Windows service written in c#. Both running on the same machine. Idea is for them to share the same database.

The Windows service acts as the engine and the web site is more of a front end showing results of calculations performed by the engine. Communication consist of commands with little data from web server to the windows service. Very few commands / second is to be expected.

What would be a good way for them to communicate?

Comment: Which kind of communication? How many transactions/messages? Amount of data?

Comment: Isn't a website and web service sharing the same database kind of pointless? Why consume the service when you can access the data directly?

Answer (score 2):

Generally the fastest on the Windows side is going to be LRPC.  Depending on your needs WCF can be a real problem.  We use Win32 LRPC + protobuffers to get about 40x faster throughput from web server to background service.  Just depends on you're needs.

(see [Benchmarking WCF compared to Protocol Buffers + RpcLibrary](http://csharptest.net/787/benchmarking-wcf-compared-to-rpclibrary/))

The [protobuf-csharp-port](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/) has most of what you need for defining the service and messages.  Then using [protobuf-csharp-rpc](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-rpc/) to provide the message serialization over a [Win32 LRPC transport layer](http://csharptest.net/projects/rpclibrary/).

Once you get past defining the protocol in protobuffers this is really easy.  It takes only a few lines of code on the client/server to create the connection and proxy class.

Again, it all depends on what you're looking for; however, IMHO there is not currently a better RPC architecture out there for the .NET Framework.  I am, of course, biased in my opinion but we've been using variations of this since 2003 and it just works.

PS: If you're building the service from scratch you might look at my guide to [Building a Windows Service Project Template](http://csharptest.net/990/building-a-windows-service-part-7-finishing-touches/).  It will get you up and running fairly quickly with *real* event logging, installation, and command-line testing.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what do you want to do. There is a number of options available: you can host a (restful or not) web service in Windows Service, you can use Remoting or WCF, etc.

But it all starts with a question: why do you need them both? What prevents you from moving the functionality of the Windows service into the Web App?

Comment: In general, one might use a windows service where there are long-running calculations occurring, or when there is work to do that is not directly related to user input from the web site.

Answer (score 0):

You could always do it 'the other way' - have your web site run a web listener and have the Windows Service connect to it.